# I want to join the 3 tables and print their result

Tags: sql

[image: diagram]

I have 3 tables, `student`, `marks`, and `subject`. I want to print the student name then subject and then marks to that subject to that particular student. And if suppose there marks entry is `null` then I want to print there as 0. Please refer the rough picture.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Your supplied schema and sample data is a sideways out of focus picture of whiteboard chicken scratch and your question is SQL 101 level stuff? No.

Comment: This is a joke right???  Your sideways image is not even readable.

Comment: I am getting neck pain. We are not going to solve that for you. Try something. Make a query, write code. If you get stuck somewhere, show us what you have done so far. Then maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make out the details in your pic, but something like this (assuming it's compatible with your particular SQL dialect).

```
select 
   student_name, subject, NVL(mark, 0) 
from
   student, subject, marks
where
   subject.student_id = student.student_id
   and mark.subject_id = subject.subject_id
order by
   student_name, subject;
```

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's almost 2018.